# VisualForce - Syntax error. Missing '}'

Tags: visualforce

I'm new to VisualForce. I'm trying to use to control Record Type of child records created via the Related List based on Record Type of parent.

However, I receive the following error message on Line 0. "Syntax Error. Missing '}'. Not entirely sure how you can have an error on line zero or how to resolve.

```
<apex:page >
    /<!--01I-->/e?retURL=%2F{!0123L0000004a7f}
    &amp;parentid={!Record.Id}
    &amp;Name={!TRIM(Record.Name)}
    &amp;RecordType=<!--0123L0000004a7k-->
</apex:page>
```

Comment: `RecordType=<!--0123L0000004a7k-->` makes no sense as you have it commented anyways, then `/<!--01I-->/e?retURL=%2F{!0123L0000004a7f}` also makes no sense either. As `{!}` in this expression syntax you are supposed to provide controller properties or global variables. Remove these 2 lines. You will still need to define `Record` in your custom controller.

Comment: It might help to include what you're trying to do in your Visualforce page. The syntax error is because of the mix of Visualforce merge tags and HTML-style comments you have in your page. Fixing the syntax error will still only leave you with a string of text on your page.

Answer (score 4):

The initial error is easy enough to fix, but you've stumbled into a rabbit hole and fixing that one error isn't going to make this visualforce page work the way you want it to.

The `{! <stuff> }` is the syntax used for *merge expressions* (documentation calls them both Visualforce expressions, and merge fields).

It's generally used to get data from a visualforce controller, controller extension, a custom setting, or from one of the system provided global variables ($Profile, $User, $Setup, etc...).

If you have a literal value (such as `0123L0000004a7f`), then you don't use a merge expression for that. You could make it work by turning it into a string (surround the id by single quotes, e.g. `{!'0123L0000004a7f'}`), but there's really no reason to use a merge expression here.

That'll solve the immediate issue. The next thing you'll run into is `{!Record.Id}` and `{!TRIM(Record.Name)}` both giving you errors.

If you want information from a particular record, you need to indicate which object you're working on. We do that by specifying the `standardController` attribute of the `<apex:page>` tag (`<apex:page standardController="Account">`).

Since you mentioned that you want this to be used from a related list, you'll need to set the standard controller to be your child object and use the `recordSetVar` attribute as well. That should automatically get you the appropriate `retURL`, but  getting at that information (for the parent record) is likely going to require you to create a controller extension.

If you're new to Visualforce, you should definitely go through the [visualforce basics module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals) on trailhead.

Honestly though, I don't think you need a visualforce page here. You should look into using a Quick Action.